# Using the .load() method stops other jquery methods from working?

Tags: jquery

i have two html pages, index.html and photo.html

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="menu">
     <ul>
    <li><p id="about">ABOUT</p></li>
    <li><p id="work">WORK</p></li>
    <li><p id="photo">PHOTO</p></li>
    <li><p id="mail">MAIL ME</p></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="photo-container">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and photo.html

```
<html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="about12">
    <h4>a-design</h4>
    <p>
    //some text     
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a javascript file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#photo').click( function () {
        $("#container").load("photo.html .about12");
        $('#photo-container h4').fadeout(5000);
            $('#photo-container p').animate({top: '150px'},1500); 
    });
});
```

When I click on the photo id, the function .load() does it's work, but afterwards, no other jquery functions will work.   Why is this?

Also, another question, is .load() is the best method to do this work: load, fadeout, and animate, or there is a better method?

Comment: Please include all the javascript libraries you are using. Are you using only jQuery? Or jQuery ui as well? This will make it easier for people to spot where the problem is.

Comment: i'm using jQuery and jQuery ui, but the problem was solved..but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

AJAX means asynchronous loading. This part:

```
$('#photo-container h4').fadeout(5000);
$('#photo-container p').animate({top: '150px'},1500);
```

Fires even before the photo-container is loaded. You need to pass it as a callback

```
$('#photo').click( function () {
    $("#container").load("photo.html .about12", function() {
        $('#photo-container h4').fadeout(5000);
        $('#photo-container p').animate({top: '150px'},1500); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery .live method is probably what you are looking for.

```
$("#photo").live("click", function(){ ... });
```

Comment: The live function is deprecated.

Comment: I guess I haven't touched jQuery in a while lol

Answer (score 0):

ajax load is asynchronus .. you need to do stuff to data on its success callback function.
use `find()` to get the dynamic added contents element. and you just need to pass url in first option of load

try this

```
$('#photo').click( function () {
    $("#container").load("photo.html",function(data){
        $(data).find('#photo-container h4').fadeout(5000);
        $(data).find('#photo-container p').animate({top: '150px'},1500);
    });

});
```